# How top Stop arranged Subview Clipping in StackView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ui-design

I have three arranged subviews inside stackView like this:
my "Rec" Label and "00:00:00" Label have their bottom and top portion clipped. i don not want that

[image: a red horizontal StackView with a Square red view , a record label and a timer label where Record Label and Timer Label are clipped by a little bit from bottom and top]

Constraints For square red View:
 Height = 10px
 Width = 10px

Constraints For "Rec" and "00:00:00" label
 - None

Constraints for StackView:'
     center vertically In Safe Area
     trailing Space to safe Area 30px

Please ignore the white background view, its there just so i could show the clipping of my labels..it does not have any constraint.

i would like a way where stackViews height gets decided by the intrinsic content size of "Rec" or "00:00:00" label. whichever has bigger height.

Comment: You've given us little information. A stackView's height is determined by its subviews' intrinsic content size. You're going to have to share the constraints for all of you views involved.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you don't use a custom font?

Comment: @Rob updated my question for clarity

Comment: @RomanPodymov I'm not using custom Font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You likely need to specify the alignment for your stackView. If you're using a storyboard, check the Attributes Inspector for your stackView. Specifying "Center" will likely do what you need. Just don't specify "Fill".

[image]

If you're configuring your stackView programatically, then all you need to do is set the alignment property this way:

```
stackView.alignment = .center
```